# MySQL join on three tables EAV model

Tags: mysql

Kindly consider the following tables:

**invoices**

```
+-----------+----+------------+--------+---------+
| accountid | id | customerid | total  | balance |
+-----------+----+------------+--------+---------+
| 1         | 2  | 167909     | 120060 | 120060  |
+-----------+----+------------+--------+---------+
```

**invoices_attributes**

```
+-----------+----+--------------+
| accountid | id | name         |
+-----------+----+--------------+
| 1         | 1  | registration |
+-----------+----+--------------+
| 1         | 2  | claimnumber  |
+-----------+----+--------------+
| 1         | 3  | jobid        |
+-----------+----+--------------+
```

**invoices_attributes_values**

```
+------------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+
| attributevalueid | attributeid | invoiceid | value         |
+------------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+
| 1                | 1           | 2         | ABC 126L      |
+------------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+
| 2                | 2           | 2         | ABZ123        |
+------------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+
| 3                | 3           | 2         | MARY DOE      |
+------------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Through the help of [Eugen Rieck's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100552/eugen-rieck) original answer I was able to make the following query

```
SELECT
  invoices.accountid,
  invoices.id AS invoiceid,
  invoices.customerid,
  invoices.total,
  registration.value AS registration,
  claimnumber.value AS claimnumber,
  jobid.value as jobid
  FROM
  invoices
  LEFT JOIN invoice_attributes ON invoices.accountid=invoice_attributes.accountid
  LEFT JOIN invoice_attribute_values AS registration ON registration.attributeid = invoice_attributes.id AND invoices.id = registration.invoiceid AND invoice_attributes.name = 'registration'
  LEFT JOIN invoice_attribute_values AS claimnumber ON claimnumber.attributeid = invoice_attributes.id AND invoices.id = claimnumber.invoiceid AND invoice_attributes.name = 'claimnumber'
  LEFT JOIN invoice_attribute_values AS jobid ON jobid.attributeid = invoice_attributes.id AND invoices.id = jobid.invoiceid AND invoice_attributes.name = 'jobid'
```

Which gave the following result

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+
| accountid | invoiceid | customerid | total  | registration | claimnumber | jobid    |
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+
| 1         | 2         | 167909     | 120060 | NULL         | NULL        | MARY DOE |
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+
| 1         | 2         | 167909     | 120060 | NULL         | ABZ123      | NULL     |
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+
| 1         | 2         | 167909     | 120060 | ABC 126L     | NULL        | NULL     |
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+
```

When I GROUP BY invoices.id some of the columns (registration, claimnumner or job) will become NULL. I desire the result to be as:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+
| accountid | invoiceid | customerid | total  | registration | claimnumber | jobid    |
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+
| 1         | 2         | 167909     | 120060 | ABC 126L     | ABZ123      | MARY DOE |
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+
```

How can the query be modified to get the result above?

Answer (score 0):

SQL has no provision to make the columns dependant on the data. You could however create a query with ALL possible attributes along the lines of

Basically you want to renormalize an EVA structure - this is of course possible:

```
SELECT
  invoices.accountid,
  invoices.id AS invoiceid
  invoices.customerid,
  invoices.total,
  jobids.value AS jobid -- one of these lines per attriubute
FROM
  invoices
  LEFT JOIN invoices_attributes ON invoices.accountid=invoices_attributes.accountid
  -- One of the following joins per attribute
  LEFT JOIN invoices_attributes_values AS jobids
    ON jobids.attr_id=invoices_attributes.attr_id
    AND jobids.accountid=invoices.accountid
    AND jobids.invoiceid=invoices.id
    AND invoices_attributes.attr_name='jobid'
```

Comment: @Eugene: I have updated the question with an actual query and it's results. I think a small tweak on it and it could work??